# How to get Image different image URIs from different Images to ImageView on CropActivity?

Tags: android, uri, android-imageview

Hey guys im new to programming in Android and i came to an issue, i have three ImageView and every time i click on these ImageViews i want it to start on CropActivity. Afterwards, if crop activity is done, it will retrieve its image Uri to the imageview i clicked. However the issue is whenever i click on ImageView 2, get the image,and then crop it, the image is set right away to the three of the ImageViews. And not on the Image View 2.  I tried searching online and cant seem to find the answer to it.

**Here is my onCreate**

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CardView profileImageEdit, profileImageEdit2, profileImageEdit3;
ImageView ivBack, ImageUploaded1, ImageUploaded2, ImageUploaded3;
Uri imageUri1, imageUri2, imageUri3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
    profileImageEdit = findViewById(R.id.profileImageEdit);
    profileImageEdit2 = findViewById(R.id.profileImageEdit2);
    profileImageEdit3 = findViewById(R.id.profileImageEdit3);
    ImageUploaded1 = findViewById(R.id.ImageUploaded1);
    ImageUploaded2 = findViewById(R.id.ImageUploaded2);
    ImageUploaded3 = findViewById(R.id.ImageUploaded3);

        profileImageEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(EditProfileActivity.this);


        }
    });



    profileImageEdit2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(EditProfileActivity.this);


        }
    });

    profileImageEdit3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(EditProfileActivity.this);


        }
    });



    ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

**below the above Line is my cropActvity onActivity result**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        imageUri1 = result.getUri();
        imageUri2 = result.getUri();
        imageUri3 = result.getUri();//this is the problem

        ImageUploaded1.setImageURI(imageUri1);
        ImageUploaded2.setImageURI(imageUri2);
        ImageUploaded3.setImageURI(imageUri3);


    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Here is the image: [EditProfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9em4.jpg)

Many thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

create new imageView instance:

`ImageView pickedImageView;`

after every profileImageEdit set it to clicked ImageView:

```
ImageView pickedImageView;
profileImageEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CropImage.activity()
                        .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                        .start(EditProfileActivity.this);
                pickedImageView = profileImageEdit;
            }
        });

        profileImageEdit2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CropImage.activity()
                        .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                        .start(EditProfileActivity.this);
                pickedImageView = profileImageEdit2;
            }
        });

        profileImageEdit3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CropImage.activity()
                        .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                        .start(EditProfileActivity.this);
                pickedImageView = profileImageEdit3;
            }
        });
```

modify your onActivityResult with following:

```
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                if (pickedImageView != null)
                    pickedImageView.setImageURI(result.getUri());
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. We tried this out but it just changes 1 imageview. Since the pickedInageView.setImageUri(result.getUri()); only returns one Uri of the selected imageview. What if i had 2 image view?